# Mysql Query returning 0 results

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Given the values in these 2 rows, why does my query return 0 rows and how can the query be rewritten to work properly?

```
meta_id post_id meta_key   meta_value
   1422      73 wpcf-milk      22
   1423      73 wpcf-mw        -7
```

SQL Query:

```
   SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE post_id = 73 
    AND ( meta_key = 'wpcf-mw' AND meta_value BETWEEN -8 AND 200 )
    AND ( meta_key = 'wpcf-milk' AND meta_value BETWEEN 20 AND 200 )
```

Comment: ( meta_key = 'wpcf-mw' AND meta_value BETWEEN -8 AND 200 ) OR ( meta_key = 'wpcf-milk' AND meta_value BETWEEN 20 AND 200 ) you must use OR

Comment: What you do mean "work properly"?  What is the way you want it to work?

Comment: Oh, the *joys* of the Entity-Attribute-Value model. Fun, fun, *fun*.

Comment: @spencer7593 That's wordpress for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two ways of doing this. One is roughly as follows:

```
SELECT post_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'wpcf-milk' THEN meta_value END) wpcf_milk
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'wpcf-mw' THEN meta_value END) wpcf_mw 
  FROM wp_postmeta 
 GROUP 
    BY post_id 
HAVING wpcf_milk BETWEEN 20 AND 200 
   AND wpcf_mw BETWEEN -8 AND 200;
```

The other approach involves OUTER JOINs and is slightly faster, but slightly more tedious to type out - so I'll leave it to others.

Comment: This worked well. Thank you for this. Am I able to use these aliases in a join statement? There is an ID stored in a meta_value field but the query keeps producing an error stating that the column doesn't exist. Should I post another question?

Comment: The answer might not be entirely straightforward, so I think you should ask a new question, but refer back to this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id = 73 
  AND (( meta_key = 'wpcf-mw' AND meta_value BETWEEN -8 AND 200 ) 
  **OR** ( meta_key = 'wpcf-milk' AND meta_value BETWEEN 20 AND 200 ))
```

Change AND by OR.

Comment: Probably should wrap the `() OR ()` in `()` for clarity, if not for boolean paranoia. ;)

Comment: @Uueerdo: I never had a name for my affliction before... **boolean paranoia**.  We *know* there's a precedence to the operators, but with parens, we can make the precedence explicit, and we never have to remember/lookup whether AND or OR has higher precedence. Maybe I'm afflicted with **boolean precedence memory impairment**. (I suspect that means the same thing as "lazy".)

Comment: I suspect that this is not what's really wanted. I suspect that the OP wants BOTH values to be true (as they are) rather than just either one of them.

Comment: Correct, both values need to be true.